# Cannot using "Overlapped" class in UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developing  an Universal app that needs to use Overlapped class. 
I've installed Overlapped from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Overlapped/. But everytime I build the app, It failed with the following error:
"The type or namespace name 'Overlapped' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Threading;


namespace test
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Overlapped tmp1; // red underline under Overlapped
            System.Threading.Overlapped tmp2; // red underline under Overlapped
        }
    }
}
```

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: Well it tells you you're missing a reference or an assembly?

Comment: Have you added a `using` statement to import the namespace?

Comment: @JoachimGotzes: No, System.Threading.Overlapped was already in reference.

Comment: @Amy: Yes I have. I added "using System.Threading".

Comment: Show us some code.  Let's not play 20 questions.

Comment: See [System.Threading namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185490.aspx)

Comment: See [UWP The type or namespace name 'Overlapped' could not be found.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0c8c6727-3101-4f81-9535-a3e53ef0a8d9/uwp-the-type-or-namespace-name-overlapped-could-not-be-found?forum=wpdevelop), or is that you also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your app's minimum version is at least the Fall Creators Update (16299) to use .Net Standard 2.0 classes.

See [Announcing UWP support for .Net Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/10/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why we must use NuGet. I suggest uninstalling System.Threading.Overlapped installed by NuGet. Then try using NativeOverlapped instead of Overlapped. I also can't use the Overlapped class in a UWP program but NativeOverlapped is found.